# Non-static variable error in android

Tags: android, variables, non-static

So I have a main class and another class that has a variable I need to pull out into the main class. I have tried some of the ways posted on the answered questions like this, but I'm still failing to get it right.

```
public class Example extends MapActivity
{
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Button bttn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast tulos = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                               "Area is: "
                                                +MyItemizedOverlay.alue +"" 
                     /*I get the non static variable error here
                       which I get as it is not yet defined, it will be after the user 
                       inputs values into the program*/
                                               ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                tulos.show();
            }
     });

public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    int alue;
        //irreleveant stuff (I assume)
    public void Calc(Geopoint gp, Mapview map){
        //there's some stuff before the variable I want to get like other variables
        //not relevant for my problem I hope

        alue = (int)Math.round(*formula: derived from user input data*)
    }
}
```

So how can I get a value out of my other class, as it doesn't seem to be able to get it now? Or is this maybe an indication of a bigger problem?

Comment: @Jimpanzee I'm confused - all the relevant classes are already in the question.

Comment: I think your last question is the most relevant: "Is this maybe an indication of a bigger problem?" The answer seems to be yes, you need to go back and cover the Java fundamentals.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the second class. I must be tired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way

1 - `make alue static` but that will show the `error that satic variable can't be accesses in non static function Calc` so either `make function Calcalso static as well` or go to point 2

2-try this `new MyItemizedOverlay().alue with making alue  public` as below

```
  public class Example extends MapActivity
    {
    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Button bttn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast tulos = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                  "Area is: "
                  +new MyItemizedOverlay().alue +"" /<--------------------
    /*I get the non static variable error here
     which I get as it is not yet defined, it will be after the user has input 
    values into the program*/
                  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           tulos.show();
             }
         });

    public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    public int alue; /<--------------------
        //irreleveant stuff (I assume)
    public void Calc(Geopoint gp, Mapview map){
        //there's some stuff before the variable I want to get like other variables
        //not relevant for my problem I hope
    alue = (int)Math.round(*formula: derived from user input data*)
    }
```

Comment: So this did something for me, though I stumbled upon on another problem. I think I may have done harm to myself by overloading those methods.

So the default access control level for variables is set to private?

Comment: sorry Lex, not get " may have done harm to myself by overloading those methods."

Answer (score 0):

There is no access modifier for `int alue` means it is default. 
Make it `public int alue` to be accessible from other classes.
Have a Look At [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)